# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE  `mealorder`.`order_item` 
( `order_id` INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
  `user_id` INT(20) NOT NULL , 
  `item_type` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
  `item_price` DOUBLE(20) NOT NULL , 
  `item_quantity` INT(20)  NULL ,
  `date_time` DATETIME(5)  NULL , 
  `total_price` DOUBLE(20)  NULL , 
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`(20))) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: what is the issue i am getting error on this

Comment: You have extra parenthesis ")"

Comment: i tried but it does'nt work

Comment: Try removing `(20)` after DOUBLE for `item_price` and `total_price` columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_item` (
   `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `item_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `item_price` double NOT NULL,
   `item_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
   `total_price` double NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain what changes you are suggesting and why they should work as a solution.